# How to hide the result table on search bar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I am not really good in coding, I need a help with my code. I have a code to search in a database. Now it's showing all the data on the database, when somebody search, it will filter out and show me result on the same table.I only want to show the result, when somebody search on the search bar, it should show me the filtered data. otherwise, my table should be hidden.

Can anybody please tell me how to do that. Thank you so much for your time.

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
        // search in all table columns
        // using concat mysql function
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `ADDRESS` WHERE CONCAT(`ID`, `STATE`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);

    }
     else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `ADDRESS`";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

    // function to connect and execute the query
    function filterTable($query)
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "dbadmin", "simplymac");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        return $filter_Result;
    }

     ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>SimplyMac PO Tracking Tool</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
           <style>

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div class="images-wrapper">

        <img class="Large" src="/dbadmin/Images/simplymac_logo.png" width="320" height="140" />
          </div>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
              <div class="wrap">
                <center><h3>PO TRACKING TOOL</h3></center>
                <center><table>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Enter Purchase Order (PO#) Number" size="100" class="searchbar"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="search" value="SEARCH" class="Button"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></center>
              </div>
               <table class="resultdata">
                   <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>ADDRESS_LINE_1</th>
                        <th>ADDRESS_LINE_2</th>
                        <th>CITY</th>
                        <th>STATE</th>
                        <th>ZIP</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ADDRESS_LINE_1'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ADDRESS_LINE_2'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['CITY'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['STATE'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ZIP'];?></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </table>
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you learned about PHP's [`if` construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)?

Comment: Remove else part of query so it don't show all data, otherwise your coding is fine

Comment: I know you are writing this with PHP, but have you looked at ajax yet? If you do it this way it will have to reload the page each time you search.

Comment: @Chris, Unfortunately, I have not, but I am definitely going to look for it. Thank sharing with me.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam, I have removed the else part, it works for the 1st time, but after your 1st search, it going to show you all the data again. Thanks

Comment: @Icewine, I am not really familiar with the ajax but i will give a try. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax for your problem.
When customer type in text box at that time call one java script function, in this function get text box value and call ajax for result table.

```js
function getResult(search)
{
 var file_path = '';//your php file path
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: file_path,
  data: search,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
   //print result in one div
  }
 });
}
```

```html
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="SEARCH" class="Button" onClick="getResult(this.value);">
```

Comment: Please for give me if I am doing this wrong. I am not really familiar ajax. I did exact the way you told me. It will disappear the   database result, but it will not return the result when I am search and submit. Please see my code below. Thank you so much for your time and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `<script> function getResult(search){ var file_path = '/dbadmin/index.php'; //your php file path $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "index.php", data: search, cache: false, success: function(result){ <div> <table class="resultdata" > <tr> <th>PO Number</th> <th>Vendor SKU</th> <th>Description</th> <th>Serial Number</th> <th>Qty.</th> </tr>`

Comment: `<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?> <tr> <td><?php echo $row['PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER'];?></td> <td><?php echo $row['INGRAM_SKU'];?></td> <td><?php echo $row['DESCRIPTION'];?></td> <td><?php echo $row['SERIAL_NUMBER'];?></td> <td><?php echo $row['QUANTITY'];?></td> </tr> <?php endwhile;?> </table> </div> //print result in one div } }); } </script> `